# <ul> <li> height expands, BUT it looks fine after refreshing the browser?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The hidden `li` (e.g. Space 01, Space 02) expands in height, when user visits the website for the first time.

Once user refreshes the browser, the height of `li` will look just fine.

How do I fix this issue? This problem only exists in IE browsers.

```css
#cssmenu {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  width: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ece6e8;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d9ced2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -o-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  
  list-style-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7);
}
#cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab {
  display: none;
  /* Hide for large screens */

}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-right: 1px solid #F1F1F1;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ece6e8;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #d9ced2;
  border-top: 0 none;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;

}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a {
  background-image: url('caret.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% -330%;
}
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a.active,
#cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a:hover {
  background: #009FDA url('caret.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 90% 430%;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 24px 11px 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #747474;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a.active,
#cssmenu > ul li a:hover {
  background: #009FDA;
  color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #cssmenu > ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab a {
    background: url('images/menu.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% -35%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li#responsive-tab a:hover {
    background-color: #009FDA;
    background-position: 95% -35%;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.right {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub {
    position: relative;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 0 none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li {
    display: block !important;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub ul li a span {
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul li.has-sub > a {
    background-image: none;
  }
}
/* Make sure they show even if hidden in mobile view by JS */
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #cssmenu > ul > li.collapsed {
    display: inline-block !important;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul ul li.collapsed {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>


<li class="has-sub">
<a href="#">
<span class="navi"><img src="http://www.kclibrary.org/sites/all/themes/kcplibraryzen/images/menu_items/menu-icon.png"></span>
<span>Test Dropdown</span></a> 
<ul>
<li>
<a href="http://www.google.com"><span>Space 01</span></a></li>
<li class="last">
<a href="http://www.google.com"><span>Space 02</span></a></li>
</ul>
</li>

</ul></div>
</html>
```